# We are getting Cloudfront 502 Error - Abortedorigin which is causing exception in our mobile application

Tags: cloud, amazon-cloudfront, http-status-code-502

We are using cloudfront distributions for our uat and production environments. There was a migration intimation from AWS starting from March 23, 2021 saying CloudFront will begin migrating the Certificate Authority for the *.cloudfront.net certificate .... before this migration we already did the following to avoid being impacted by this:

- Imported our custom SSL into Amazon Certificate Manager.
- Created an Alias for Cloudfront Distribution.
- Configured Cloudfront to use custom SSL instead *.cloudfront.net
- Created the relevant DNS entry for the alias in Route53.

After implementing the above mentioned things, the communication between end user through cloudfront to our origin server was perfectly working fine. But starting from (March 23, 2021 - The migration date) we are getting 502 error intermittently. Nothing is changed on our end.
The cloudfront S3 logs shows:

2021-03-30 7:26:10 MAA51-C2 1158 103.149.159.8 POST xxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net /galileo/getAccountBalanceNDetails 502 - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/5.2.1 - - Error eJlWt84icw_Ytc_t3jv0VrYXZXv51lNWfWxxHaksXbSxgKc27BQ== xxxx.xxxx.com https 3277 0.086 - TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 Error HTTP/2.0 - - 3173 0.086 **AbortedOrigin** text/html 936 - -

AWS support also investigated the issue as per guidelines given in:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/http-502-bad-gateway.html

but did not get any misconfigurations or issue on cloudfront side.

Any help in this regard would highly be appreciated.

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue. Were you able to find a solution to this problem?